# Python - Error Search of BST

Tags: search, binary-search-tree, python-3.6, nonetype

I have a problem with an BST (Binary Search Tree) or ABB in Spanish. My problem is that the fuction search(), or buscar() in Spanish, doesn't work. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Here is the code:

```css
#TAD de Árbol Binario de Búsqueda
class ABB(object):
 def __init__(self, data):
     self.right = None 
  self.left = None 
  self.data = data 

 def insert(self, data):
  if self.data: 
   if data < self.data: 
    if self.left == None: 
     self.left = ABB(data) 
    else: 
     self.left.insert(data) 
   elif data > self.data: 
    if self.right == None: 
     self.right = ABB(data) 
    else: 
     self.right.insert(data) 
  else: 
   self.data = data 

 def buscar(self, x):
  while x != self.data and self.data != None:
   if self.data < x:
    self.left.buscar(x)
   else:
    self.right.buscar(x)
  if self.data == x:
   return True
  if self.data == None:
   return False

n = ABB(8)
n.insert(3)
n.insert(10)
n.insert(1)
n.insert(6)
n.insert(4)
n.insert(7)
n.insert(14)
n.insert(13)
print("existe?",n.buscar(22))
```

It is supposed to return true or false if the searched number exists or not. And in both cases that does not happen.
The error message is:

```html
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'buscar'
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  You can see from the last entry in the trace of your error log that call to `self.left.buscar(x)` is causing an issue.  The buscar() method does not exist within self.left, because self.left is not an ABB object.  Please update your question as you continue to investigate and make sure to [add an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) if you figure it out on your own.

Comment: @AndrewKozak Excuse me, but there is a search method for left because when the left child is created, it obtains the BST attributes and methods, since it is instantiated as such.